# Ant Design Dropdown - Access props value inside children menus [ React ]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-props

I have a list of posts like facebook feed, every single post has a dropdown with "edit,delete,report".

I use Ant Design UI, the problem is I can't access the props value "DeleteId" inside the children menus.

But I can access props values (deleteId) inside the component.

According to Ant Design [here](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/) , children menus (menu) are declared outside the component.

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/poepoe/pen/KxedoR?editors=0010)

```
//-------------- Outside Component --------------------

const onClick = function (info) {
  console.log(info)
};

const menu = (
  <Menu onClick={onClick}>

    { 
     // this.props.deleteId  <=== this doesn't work, props value is "undefined"
    }

    <Menu.Item key="1">Edit</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="delete-Id-here">Delete</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="3">Report</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

//-------------- Inside Component --------------------

class Demo extends React.Component {
   render(){

     console.log("deleteId = "+ this.props.deleteId +" ( Inside component ) ")
// this.props.deleteId  <=== This props value works fine, I can access all props data inside component

     return (
  <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
       <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
        <Icon style={{fontSize:24}} type="ellipsis" theme="outlined" />
    </a>
  </Dropdown>
     )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Demo deleteId="123456"/>,
  mountNode);
```

Probably, it doesn't know "props" values inside children menus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that you're just missing passing on the props to your `menu` functional component.
Below is modified code to pass `deleteId` as a parameter to the `menu` function.

```
const menu = (deleteId) => (
  <Menu onClick={onClick}>
    <Menu.Item key="1">Edit</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="delete-Id-here">Delete {deleteId}</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="3">Report</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

`Demo`

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Dropdown overlay={menu(this.props.deleteId)}>
        <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
          <Icon style={{fontSize:24}} type="ellipsis" theme="outlined" />
        </a>
      </Dropdown>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not an optimal solution we end up calling the `menu` function several times.